# Eclipse Egit not picking up configured remote repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have since upgraded to Juno and the latest version of Egit. However, i noticed that when i attempt to push to a remote repository, the configured remote repository is defaulting to some random repository URL that isn't associated with my repository. the configured one seems to be picked up from some other location. has anyone seen this behavior? i checked my repository and see the proper remote URL present.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use on of those menus which invokes the [Push Wizard](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Wizard). That one allows to push to arbitrary locations, independent of the current repository. Instead of doing this all the time, please configure an [upstream configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Upstream_Configuration), so you can [push to upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pushing_to_upstream) without any location selection.

If you really work with multiple remotes and want to push to more than one repository regularly, then you should have each of those [remotes configured with its specific push URL and specification](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories). That way you can push to different remotes by just selection the push context menu on a remote (without any additional selection).